# Combine v-bind and v-for in vue.js (and webpack) v-bind ignored

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to bind an inline style to a div that contains v-for. But it seems to always ignore the v-bind. Here is the template and the data.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-bind:style="styleObject" v-for="collection in collections" :key="collection.id">       
       <a v-bind:href="collection.pageurl">  
         <h1>{{ collection.title }}</h1>
         <h2>{{ collection.author }}</h2>             
      </a>   
    </div>
    <router-view/>
    </div>
    </template>
```

...and here is the script code in the same .vue file:

```
export default {
  name: "app",
  styleObject: {
    background: "red",
    borderColor: "red"
  },
  //Pass data to the app.
  firebase: {
    collections: collectionsRef
  }
};
```

The background image will come from the table, but I can't even get this simple static example to work. Everything renders as expected except the v-bind is ignored. When I inspect in chrome the style= isn't even in the div tag. I copied the v-bind code out of the vue.js docs. I am using vue-cli with webpack.

No error message, code compiles fine. The v-bind is just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`styleObject` needs to be part of the data for the component, or a computed property. I'm assuming `collectionsRef` is working properly for you although it appears to be undefined based on the posted code.

```
export default {
  name: "app",
  data(){
    return {
      styleObject: {
        background: "red",
        borderColor: "red"
      }, 
    }
  },
  //Pass data to the app.
  firebase: {
    collections: collectionsRef
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I looked all over and never saw that syntax. (The collectionsRef is defined elsewhere as data coming from a firebase project).

Comment: You're using a component, so data must be a function that returns an object. This is discussed in first few paragraphs of the [documentation on components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function). If you haven't read it yet, the documentation is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like this.

```
data : return{
   styleObject: {
    background: "red",
    borderColor: "red"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Send me your JS